# Swift: call tuple member with variable?

Tags: variables, swift2, tuples, member

Basic question. If I have the following:

```
let unitPrice = (fighter: 15, cleric: 20, mage: 25)
var unitType = "cleric"
```

How do I call `unitPrice.unitType`

So that it equals `unitPrice.cleric` (20)?

Comment: If i am right you don't want to add unitType inside your tuple right?

Comment: That is correct, I do not. I want to call unitPrice.cleric (for example) using a variable instead of the term "cleric"

Comment: Try extracting value from its index. Index starts from zero. e:g unitPrice.1

Comment: Ok, but if unitType = 1, then unitPrice.unitType still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're really looking for is a Dictionary, not a tuple.
Try the following:

```
// Using an enum instead of a String ensures there are no errors from spelling mistakes.
enum UnitType {
    case Fighter
    case Cleric
    case Mage
}

let unitPrice: [UnitType : Int] = [.Fighter : 15, .Cleric : 20, .Mage : 25]

// Retrieving the price of a Cleric...
let type = UnitType.Cleric
if let price = unitPrice[type] {
    print(price) // 20
}
```